# Can the fancybox2 play videos offline if I have all the files?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

Hi I have been working offline on trying to get a video to play which is in my files and it wouldn't work.  I have uploaded the files onto the server and they are playing.  Is there anyway I can have them work offline?  Thanks

Comment: The short answer is yes, it can ... but depends on the type of videos, the player, the browser and the operating system. It would with .flv or mp4 videos and some old versions of jwplayer but not with flowplayer for instance. Since it's local, you are on your own ;)

Comment: Thank you for your reply JKF, I am calling a html page with mp4 video, the player is the fancybox2, browser Chrome and Windows7 operating system.  I used to be able to use the earlier version of the fancybox offline but really want to use the new fancybox2

Comment: When working "offline", are you trying to view a static HTML page from a directory, or is it being served through a local server?

Comment: I am calling a static HTML page from my directory, it is not being served through a local server.  I used to be able to do it with the old player but haven't so far with this new Fancybox 2?

Comment: Can you post a stripped-down version of what you're doing? Are the Developer tools reporting any errors?

Comment: Tieson, I will put it up on the server again tomorrow and send the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using fancybox v2.x you could watch **mp4** videos offline as `iframe` ...so having this html

```
<a class="fancybox" href="video.mp4">open video</a>
```

...this code should work (offline) in Chrome and Firefox ... other browsers (like Opera and even IE) may require the *quicktime* plugin.

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    type: "iframe",
    // optionally set fixed dimensions
    width: 420, // or whatever
    height : 380 
});
```

**NOTE**: Other type of videos like `.flv` may require other tricks and a video player.

Comment: Thank you JFK I will try this tomorrow and let you know how I get on. I have been using the below script as this is supposed to cater for iframes?<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".various").fancybox({
  maxWidth : 800,
  maxHeight : 600,
  fitToView : false,
  width  : '70%',
  height  : '70%',
  autoSize : false,
  closeClick : false,
  openEffect : 'none',
  closeEffect : 'none'
 });

Comment: you always need to specify the type like `type: "iframe"` or as a class like `class="fancybox fancybox.iframe"`

Comment: Finally got it to work!! For some reason I needed to path the video using the dot for offline e.g. <script type="text/javascript" src="./fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.4"></script>  Thank you for your input JKF and Tieson.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it to work!! For some reason I needed to path the video using the dot for offline e.g. script type="text/javascript" src="./fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.4" Thank you for your input JKF and Tieson.